# python(twisted) gives error in openssl installation in MAC?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, twisted

I have installed Openssl in MAC(V 10.11.3)

```
# brew upgrade
#brew install openssl
Warning: openssl 1.0.2l is already installed
```

I ran  following commands too;

```
easy_install PyOpenSSL

easy_install PyCrypto
```

All these commands installed without issue.

And tried to link openssl with brew

```
#brew link openssl
```

And getting

```
Warning: Refusing to link: openssl

    Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
    deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
    Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
      -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

But If I try;

```
 brew link /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin --force (or, **lib**, **include** folders)
```

I get same for all locations

```
Error: No available formula with the name "/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin"
```

Now when I try in the python command prompt;

```
>>> from twisted.internet import reactor, endpoints
```

I get following error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OP_NO_TLSv1_1'
```

Full error stack

```
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Twisted-17.9.0rc1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/twisted/internet/reactor.py", line 38, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import default
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Twisted-17.9.0rc1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/twisted/internet/default.py", line 56, in <module>
    install = _getInstallFunction(platform)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Twisted-17.9.0rc1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/twisted/internet/default.py", line 50, in _getInstallFunction
    from twisted.internet.selectreactor import install
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Twisted-17.9.0rc1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/twisted/internet/selectreactor.py", line 18, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import posixbase
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Twisted-17.9.0rc1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/twisted/internet/posixbase.py", line 18, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import error, udp, tcp
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Twisted-17.9.0rc1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 28, in <module>
    from twisted.internet._newtls import (
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Twisted-17.9.0rc1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/twisted/internet/_newtls.py", line 21, in <module>
    from twisted.protocols.tls import TLSMemoryBIOFactory, TLSMemoryBIOProtocol
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Twisted-17.9.0rc1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/twisted/protocols/tls.py", line 63, in <module>
    from twisted.internet._sslverify import _setAcceptableProtocols
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Twisted-17.9.0rc1-py2.7-macosx-10.11-intel.egg/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 38, in <module>
    TLSVersion.TLSv1_1: SSL.OP_NO_TLSv1_1,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OP_NO_TLSv1_1'
>>>
```

How can I overcome this issue?

**EDIT**

If I try

```
>>> import OpenSSL
```

Nothing printed

But if I try

```
>>> import twisted.internet.ssl
```

I get above mentioned issue.

I have following twisted version installed;

```
>>> import twisted
>>> twisted.__version__
'17.9.0rc1'
>>>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have overcome the issue by installing latest version of the **twisted**

```
#sudo pip install twisted==13.1.0
```

Comment: That is neither the latest version of Twisted nor the correct way to install it (`sudo pip ...`) on any system. :/